# how to display day name in twig date in symfony

Tags: php, twig

I am using twig in php and want to display the full name of the current day in the date how can i do that. This is my code

```
{{ "now"|date("d,  F Y ","America/Denver") }}
```

Answer (score 12):

This prints the current day:

```
{{ "now"|date('l') }}
```

See also (for other format string components): http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php